# How can I recreate the following table?

Tags: java, arrays, if-statement

[image]

Hello everyone, I'm trying to re-create the table above for an assignment and I'm stuck due to errors concerning the && function. Note that we are not allowed to use arrays and are limited to "switch" and "If"

This is what I've got so far:

```
if ((BEAK_MM == 1) && (CLAW_MM == 0) && (COLOR = "Grey")) {
   System.out.println ("The type of bird is A.");}
else if ((BEAK_MM == 2) && (CLAW_MM == 1) && (COLOR = "Grey")) 
   System.out.println ("The type of bird is A.");}
else if ((BEAK_MM == 3) && (CLAW_MM == 2) && (COLOR = "Grey")) 
   System.out.println ("The type of bird is A.");}
else if ((BEAK_MM == 4) && (CLAW_MM == 3) && (COLOR = "Grey")) 
   System.out.println ("The type of bird is A.");}
else if ((BEAK_MM <= 4.5) && (CLAW_MM == 4) && (COLOR = "Grey")) 
   System.out.println ("The type of bird is A.");}
```

Comment: this is JAVA, not javascript, they are two very different programming languages

Comment: `COLOR ` is a String, you can't compare if Strings are equal using `==`

Comment: COLOR = "Grey" is an assignment, not a check for equality.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `BEAK` and `CLAW` are integers and `COLOR` is a `String`, then the table could be arranged more like:

```
// must be grey
if ("Grey".equals(COLOR)) {
  if ((BEAK_MM == 1 && CLAW_MM == 0)
      || (BEAK_MM == 2 && CLAW_MM == 1)
      || (BEAK_MM == 3 && CLAW_MM AW == 2)
      || (BEAK_MM == 4 && CLAW_MM == 3)
      || ( (BEAK_MM == 4 || BEAK_MM == 5) && CLAW_MM == 4))) {
     System.out.println("The bird is the word");
  }
}
```

The logic here is that according to the table, Bird Type A must be Grey. There are then some specific checks as to beak and claw types, but if it is not Grey, it is not a type A bird. There is also no need for all of the OP's stacked 'else if' statements.

There are many other approaches to solve the problem space, but I'm going with the limits of no arrays, and therefore presumably no other useful data structures such as `List` or `Set`.

As noted by @Nicholas K, `String` objects must be compared with `.equals()`.

I'd also move this stuff to a method `isBirdTypeA(int beak, int claw, String color) { ... }`

```
@Test
public void testBirds()
{
    final String G = "Grey";
    final String P = "Pink";

    assertTrue(isBirdTypeA(1, 0, G));
    assertFalse(isBirdTypeA(1, 0, P));
    assertTrue(isBirdTypeA(2, 1, G));
    assertTrue(isBirdTypeA(3, 2, G));
    assertTrue(isBirdTypeA(4, 3, G));
    assertTrue(isBirdTypeA(4, 4, G));
    assertTrue(isBirdTypeA(5, 4, G));
    assertFalse(isBirdTypeA(4, 5, G));
    assertFalse(isBirdTypeA(4, 0, G));
    assertFalse(isBirdTypeA(1, 1, G));

}


private static boolean isBirdTypeA(int beak, int claw, String color)
{
    if ("Grey".equals(color)) {
        if ((beak == 1 && claw == 0)
            || (beak == 2 && claw == 1)
            || (beak == 3 && claw == 2)
            || (beak == 4 && claw == 3)
            || ( (beak == 4 || beak == 5) && claw == 4)) {
                return true;
            }
    }
    return false; 
}


public static void main(String[] args) {
  int BEAK_MM = Integer.parseInt(args[0]);
  int CLAW_MM = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
  String COLOR = args[2];

  if (isBirdTypeA(BEAK_MM, CLAW_MM, COLOR)) {
    System.out.println("The type of bird is A");
  }
}
```

> $ java BirdBeak 1 0 Grey
>   The type of bird is A

Comment: @Yellowwhale, I am not following your comment. "Grey" is not an integer; it is a `String`. And if by "given" you mean entered by a user, that is essentially what the `testBirds()` method above does. It can be adapted to `if (isBirdTypeA(BEAK_MM, CLAW_MM, COLOR)) { System.out.println("The type is A"); }` without issue.

Comment: Sorry you're right. I made a mistake and wrote int instead of String earlier in my code which changed damaged everything else :P thank you so much!